# iOS app in AppStore not working same as in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, app-store, uicollectionview

I uploaded application to App Store. The application worked perfect in Xcode with real device and simulator. However when I downloaded app from appStore after being published, touch event of `UICollectionView` are gone.   That is,

[image]

As you can see, there are 2 UICollectionView in the screen. The bottom one is, horizontal UICollectionView. Non of these view are touchable and scrollable when downloaded from appStore.
But works perfectly in Xcode. Any recommendations? Maybe something must be done in settings before publishing to appStore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The binary remains the same for appstore and dev. Only certificates change. You are having issue because of something else.

Comment: I mean, the same code but not scrollable and touchable. Even the screen does not recognize the tap events

Answer (score 1):

You might have made some changes in the binary before uploading to App Store.

Comment: I checked several times, but for making sure, I uploaded the update for the application in order to see. But if not, I think technical support can help me yes?